# Why can I create a Worgen character without Cataclysm on my account?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My Battle.net account only contains World of Warcraft and The Burning Crusade. However, I've noticed that I can create a Worgen character, even without the later expansions installed. Why is this?

Comment: Are you asking if you have to buy LK and Cata. Or are you asking if you can play a Worgen?

Comment: No, I only have BC but I can play a worgen.  So why do I need LK and Cat to play a Monk when I get Panderia?

Comment: You should have to have upgraded to Cata to be able to play a Worgen (unless they changed something recently?). Easiest way to check what version(s) you have is to just go to http://battle.net then go to your account and click on Warcraft. If you only have BC on that account and you can make a Worgen, I'm not sure how that is happening. If this is the case, I'm guessing Blizzard will find out about it for Panda's and probably fix it.

Comment: No - this is now normal behaviour, since the release of the Mists of Pandaria pre-patch, all races are available to all players regardless of product level, meaning if you have Vanilla+TBC/Battle Chest you can still create a Worgen, Goblin, and - with the release of MoP, Pandaren.

Answer (score 6):

With the release of 5.0.4, all races except Pandaren [are now available](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/6994738/All_Races_Available_in_Patch_504-8_16_2012) to all no matter what expansions they have on their account.

Once *Mists of Pandaria* is released, you will also be able to make Pandaren.

Comment: In your source it also mentions that pandaren will be available regardless of which expansion you own by time MoP comes out.

Comment: @leety I also edited it in when I added the source, but Mark was a bit fast with his first edit

Comment: Someone suggested an edit during the 5 minute edit grace period: I didn't catch that, so when I approved and improved it as normal, it caused havoc when you edited during the grace period. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks to all.  I found out I had LK installed too.  Forgot I had it.   Still don't remember when I got it but hey that was 3 years ago right!  Guess I need Caty before I get Panderia

Comment: @Kent if you use scroll of resurrection you get cata for free, but I guess you have already activated since you know you can make worgan

Answer (score 2):

Races are no longer locked to expansions.  You can download the free-to-play version of WoW and create a character of any race available in the game.

---

Classes which were introduced in expansions are still locked to those expansions.

You must have *Wrath of the Lich King* to make a Death Knight (as well as meeting the other requirements).

You must have *Mists of Pandaria* to make a Monk.

Note: all Subscribers automatically get [Wrath](http://us.battle.net//wow/en/blog/7315726) and [Cataclysm](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/11275287/a-new-age-has-begun-world-of-warcraft-now-includes-cataclysm-10-15-2013).